# REACT: How could we use an external library as a script, into a class or functional component? Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

***Hello and than you for reading this question!***

I have a use case which I have to load a TIFF image.

So then I have researched how to use this library:
https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js

In addition, there is a great example of its use, thanks to @K3N
[Display Existing TIFF File Using the seikichi/tiff Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42847915/display-existing-tiff-file-using-the-seikichi-tiff-library)

The difficulty I am facing is trying to integrate the previous use example with React.

I have tried the following:

To create a class component which loads the script and appends it to the document:

LoadTIFF.js

```
import React from 'react';

class LoadTIFF extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        const script = document.createElement("script");

        script.src = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/seikichi/tiff.js/master/tiff.min.js";
        script.async = true;

        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            document.querySelector("input").onchange = function () {

                // convert File blob to ArrayBuffer using a FileReader
                var fileReader = new FileReader();

                fileReader.onload = function () {                     // file is now ArrayBuffer:
                    var tiff = new Tiff({buffer: this.result});        // parse and convert
                    var canvas = tiff.toCanvas();                      // convert to canvas
                    document.querySelector("div").appendChild(canvas); // show canvas with content
                };

                fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0]);         // convert selected file
            }
        );

    }
}

export {LoadTIFF};
```

And then I have tried to use it from a parent component which aim is to display a title and a canvas, Canvas.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {LoadTIFF} from "./LoadTIFF";


class Canvas extends React.Component {

    //A canvas to display images with a title

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="previewComponent">
                <div className="imgPreview">
                    {this.props.title}
                    <LoadTIFF/>
                    <canvas></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export {Canvas};
```

And the console's output is:

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
    in LoadTIFF (at Canvas.js:14)
    in div (at Canvas.js:12)
    in div (at Canvas.js:11)
    in Canvas (at CanvasHorizontalSplitterLayout.js:12)
    in div (at CanvasHorizontalSplitterLayout.js:11)
    in div (created by o)
    in o (created by t)
    in div (created by t)
    in t (at CanvasHorizontalSplitterLayout.js:10)
    in CanvasHorizontalSplitterLayout (at Caballo.js:35)
    in div (at Caballo.js:34)
    in div (created by o)
    in o (created by t)
    in div (created by t)
    in t (at Caballo.js:33)
    in main (at Caballo.js:31)
    in Caballo (created by Route)
    in Route (at Main.js:14)
    in Switch (at Main.js:12)
    in main (at Main.js:11)
    in Main (at index.js:17)
    in div (at index.js:15)
    in App (at index.js:24)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at index.js:23)
__stack_frame_overlay_proxy_console__ @ index.js:2178
printWarning @ warning.js:33
warning @ warning.js:57
warnOnFunctionType @ react-dom.development.js:6760
reconcileChildFibers @ react-dom.development.js:7664
reconcileChildrenAtExpirationTime @ react-dom.development.js:7756
reconcileChildren @ react-dom.development.js:7747
finishClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:7881
updateClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:7850
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:8225
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:10224
workLoop @ react-dom.development.js:10288
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:542
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:581
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:438
renderRoot @ react-dom.development.js:10366
performWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:11014
performWork @ react-dom.development.js:10967
requestWork @ react-dom.development.js:10878
scheduleWorkImpl @ react-dom.development.js:10732
scheduleWork @ react-dom.development.js:10689
scheduleTopLevelUpdate @ react-dom.development.js:11193
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:11231
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:15226
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:11102
renderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:15225
render @ react-dom.development.js:15290
./src/index.js @ index.js:22
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 5c657e191a78fa604491:678
fn @ bootstrap 5c657e191a78fa604491:88
0 @ index.js:23
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 5c657e191a78fa604491:678
./node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js.module.exports @ bootstrap 5c657e191a78fa604491:724
(anonymous) @ bootstrap 5c657e191a78fa604491:724
```

**Could you help me please?**

I have also read:

[Adding script tag to React/JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424845/adding-script-tag-to-react-jsx)

Thank you for your help!

EDIT1:

*Thanks to @Dragoş Paul Marinescu and specially to @Boy With Silver Wings 
I have tried @Boy With Silver Wings's example in a new React app, as you can see here: https://github.com/YoneMoreno/ReadTiffReactApp*

The console output is the following:

```
./src/App.js
  Line 14:  Unexpected use of 'event'  no-restricted-globals
  Line 16:  'Tiff' is not defined      no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

About the event usage, it looks like we can not use it as a global variable so instead it should be used from function's props' events: [Unexpected use of 'event' no-restricted-globals when using event.target.id to get id from bind(this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44596025/unexpected-use-of-event-no-restricted-globals-when-using-event-target-id-to-ge)

So we should pass event as a prop to onChange:

```
onChange(event) {
        const canvasNode = this.canvas;
        const fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);
        fileReader.onload = function () {
            const tiff = new Tiff({
                buffer: this.result
            });
            const canvas = tiff.toCanvas();
            canvasNode.appendChild(canvas);
        };

    }
```

For the second issue, it looks like it needs to be declared a a global explicity:

[My script for react-google-maps don't loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46540253/my-script-for-react-google-maps-dont-loads)

**With those two changes it works well.**

Comment: Just include the `script` tag in your `index.html` and use it normally in any of your components.

Comment: You have to return valid html from `LoadTiff`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the function in onChange handler and put the corresponding html in render() method:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }
  onChange(file) {
    const canvasNode = this.canvas;
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);
    fileReader.onload = function() {
      const tiff = new Tiff({
        buffer: this.result
      });
      const canvas = tiff.toCanvas();
      canvasNode.appendChild(canvas);
    };
  
  }
  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        <label>
         Select TIFF file:
         <input type="file" onChange={this.onChange} />
        </label>
        <span ref={(canvas)=>this.canvas=canvas}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/seikichi/tiff.js/master/tiff.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

We are using `ref` which is the React recommended way to selecting nodes from the DOM if we needed to do that.